# Entity name not found by its mid in freebase

Tags: freebase

We are working on a research project for answering questions with a knowledge base. We adopted the dataset SimpleQuestions (https://research.fb.com/projects/babi/).
We loaded the latest freebase data dump into Virtuoso, and query entities' names by their mids (using relations type.object.name and common.topic.alias). However, many entities' names cannot be found.

We also use the KB provided by Sempre (https://github.com/percyliang/sempre), where we find more entities' name but not all.
We are guessing that these entities might be deleted, is that true? If so, how can we continue to work on this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The Freebase API has been [depreciated](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) and it is not possible to obtain entity names. However, Google has provided [Freebase/Wikidata Mappings](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) for 2.1M entities. These mappings could be used to map the freebase entity to wikidata entities and obtain their entity names and other information.

Additionally, http://sameas.org/ provides some additional mappings for freebase entities.

Edit:
You can also read the [Freebase Dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) to get these mappings. I personally used the following properties to get the corresponding entity names:

```
ENTITY_GET_LABEL_ORDER = [
    '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.name>', 
    '<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.alias>',
    '<http://rdf.freebase.com/key/en>',
    '<http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en>',
    '<http://rdf.freebase.com/key/wikipedia.en_title>',
    ]
```

Also, even after doing this, there were a good amount (~1-5k, do not remember it exactly) mids that we were unable to map to names, and one could safely remove those (only a small number of such) questions. [Google](https://developers.google.com/freebase/) also provides an additional dump which contains some deleted tuples.